# Node mcu esp8266 disconnects from MQTT broker

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp8266, mosquitto, nodemcu

I have two node mcu modules connected to the same network, running the same code and powered the same way. Both of them are subscribed to the topic Terma but one of them randomly disconnects and then reconnects to the MQTT broker meanwhile it stayed connected to the wifi uninterruptedly, the other module stays connected with no problem. I don't know if it is a network issue or if the node mcu is damaged.

here is the code:

```
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Update these with values suitable for your network.

const char* ssid = "Milagros";
const char* password = "18095381";
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.1.133";

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
long lastMsg = 0;
char msg[50];
int value = 0;

void setup_wifi() {

  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
    digitalWrite(14, LOW); 
     client.publish("estado","1");
    // but actually the LED is on; this is because
    // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  } else {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
     client.publish("estado","0");
     }

}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("terma", "hello world 1");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("terma");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the BUILTIN_LED pin as an output
  Serial.begin(115200);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1884);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void loop() {

  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

 
}
```

Comment: There could be many reasons. How often you receive subscribed message and how often the disconnect happened?

Comment: I don't think this would be the case because I publish a message every 5 minutes on average.. It randomly disconnects in the space of time of 10 minutes, meanwhile the other node mcu stays connected.

Comment: What do the logs from the broker show?

Comment: From the code you shown, I don't see where you publish every 5 minutes, in fact, it only publish _after_ receiving a subscribed msg. So if there is no msg received, no publishing. If you do publish every 5 minutes (or ping in every 5 minute), then shown the code it does...

Comment: I was trying to say that the node-mcu just publish when is connected to the MQTT broker but it receives a message every 5 minutes on average from my node-red dashboard buttons.

Comment: @romkey This is shown in the mosquitto log : "1636598072: Client ESP8266Client-718a has exceeded timeout, disconnecting."